# Getting Proxied user object in django templates

Tags: python, django, proxy, django-authentication

I have `MyUser` as proxied `User` Model.

### Model

```
class MyUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        ordering = ['username']
    @property
        def keywords(self):
            return u','.join(self.get_full_name().split())
```

I am rendering my html as follows.

### Views

```
return render_to_response('new/view_image.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, ctx))
```

### settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
)
```

In templates when i call `{{ user }}` I get `User` Object, on what i can call all the methods like, `user.is_authenticated` etc.

But The problem is I have some properties defined in my proxied model, and I want to use those when i access user object.
I mean I need `{{ user }}` to be an instance of `MyUser`.

Please let me know if you did'nt follow along.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you not to turn `request.user` to your proxy instance, because Django, internally may expect it to be instance of `User` model.

What you can do is to add property to the `User` model through wich you will access your proxy instance.

e.g.

```
class MyUser(User):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    @property
    def keywords(self):
        return u','.join(self.get_full_name().split())



def proxy_access_fn(self):
    return MyUser.objects.get(id=self.id)


setattr(User, 'my_proxy', property(proxy_access_fn))
```

Then in template you will access it like:

```
{{ user.my_proxy.keywords }}
```

I'm sure there's way how to turn model instance into proxy-model instance without hitting database but this implementation is just to show the idea.

Comment: proxy_access_fn is part of MyUser class?

Comment: Nope. It's standalone function.

Comment: Dude u r using `self` in proxy_access_fn?

Comment: Yes. To indicate that it'll work as property or rather bound method on class instance. After setting it on ``User`` with ``setattr`` that's exactly how it behave.

Comment: Awesome, thats fast, clean and it does the job. +1 dude.